# Jquery help to loop function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, minify

I have a function timeAgo to which i have to pass timestamp like this...
`$.timeAgo(timeStamp);`
it replaces the text with a specific time format.

I have huge ul li structure like this..

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
<li class="cell">
<div class="timeStamp"></div>
</li>
<li class="cell">
<div class="timeStamp"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

hw do i loop the function call? How do i write it in minified way?

Comment: Don't worry about minification just yet. Functionality, then testing, then optimization, _then_ minification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the divs with class 'timeStamp' hold the timestamp values, you can loop through them like this:

```
$( '.timeStamp' ).each( function() {
    $( this ).text( $.timeAgo( $this.text() ) );
});
```